# GRUB is not initialising the video upon boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I installed Ubuntu 19.04 alongside Windows 10 on my laptop using the "install alongside windows" option.

**My problem is that when I boot, grub is there but it doesn't initialise the VGA controller.** I can blindly use it by I can selecting a different OS, open a console or anything that is avalaible in grub but I just can't see anything.

*However,* if before booting on grub go to my BIOS settings and tell it to boot on "ubuntu" (other option is windows boot manager), it does boot on grub and it is visible and works as expected.

the question is: *Why doesn't booting without going to the BIOS   not initialise the VGA controller whereas going to the BIOS makes it behave normally?*

Things I have already checked :

- List item
- Fast boot and secure boot disabled in BIOS
- UEFI mode selected
- Used grub customizer to add a grub theme, which is showing when manually booting on grub
- I tried to change video driver from NVIDIA to xorg, doesn't change anything
- I performed a boot repair (reinstalled grub)
- I changed grub settings from "quiet splash" to "nomodeset" it only made it worse, I could't even boot at all after the invisible grub menu.
- Ubuntu is set as number 1 in the boot order in the BIOS
- Tried pressing or holding or smashing <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>ESC</kbd> during boot without success

Comment: In the duplicate skip the difficult instructions and first try the part where in BIOS you set the **Ubuntu** boot option higher than the **Windows** boot option.

Comment: I forgot to say that I already tried to hold shift or ESC during boot without success. And Ubuntu is set as my number 1 boot order. In fact my pc boots on grub but nothing is visible (it reacts to keyboard inputs as expected).

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! **:-)** Unfortunately, this is a problem in your BIOS / UEFI firmware, *before Ubuntu even comes into the picture*, **which makes this off-topic here**, but still on-topic on https://superuser.com, a sister site to [ubuntu.se]

Comment: **FIXED** : This was a problem of ubuntu 19.04. Not my BIOS. It works with ubuntu 18.04. My question isn't awnsered in the "duplicate", problem is not the same. I found a workaround : **enabling console mode** in grub works and grub shows up. It's in console mode so it is only a workaround but still better than nothing.

Comment: To do so un-comment "GRUB_TERMINAL" in the /etc/default/grub file.